# Problema animation: para Slider Automático con CSS en Microsoft Edge

Tags: html5, css3, slider, animación

Saludos a todos y gracias de antemano.

Estoy teniendo problemas para ejecutar correctamente el movimiento de las imágenes en un slide hecho con html y css.

El problema aparece únicamente en Microsoft Edge. En opera, safari, firefox, chrome e inclusive ie11 funciona perfectamente.

Apenas empieza a deslizarse la primera imagen e ir a la posición "margin-left: -100%" justo cuando parece que todo va de maravilla repentinamente vuelve quedándose estancada en mitad del camino y posteriormente bloquea el recorrido de las siguientes imágenes.

Llevo un rato probando opciones.. he añadido las correspondientes etiquetas -webkit-, -moz-, -o-, -ms- pero nada ha dado resultado.

A ver si alguien con más conocimientos pudiera echarme un cable... añado que la aplicación la estoy tomando de un ejercicio en uno de los canales de youtube: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oP5472drWiI

**HTML principal:**

```
   <div class="slider">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="imgs/slider/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="imgs/slider/2.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="imgs/slider/3.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="imgs/slider/4.jpg" alt=""></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.slider {
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider ul {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    width: 400%;
    
    animation: cambio 20s infinite alternate linear;
}

.slider li {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}

.slider img {
    width: 100%;
}

@keyframes cambio {
    0% {margin-left: 0;}
    20% {margin-left: 0;}
    
    25% {margin-left: -100%;}
    45%{margin-left: -100%;}
    
    50% {margin-left: -200%;}
    70% {margin-left: -200%;}
    
    75% {margin-left: -300%;}
    100% {margin-left: -300%;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Arreglado *

Al final como casi una gran mayoría de veces ocurre con estas cosas resultó ser "una tontería".

Supuestamente creo recordar que probé a cambiar ese parámetro en las primeras pruebas cuando detecté el mal funcionamiento en edge. Sin embargo, en esta última prueba incluso después de cambiar el parámetro y limpiar el historial, cache, etc del navegador todavía no me detectaba el código actualizado...

Después de tener que refrescar como tres o cuatro veces el navegador después de limpiar la cache por fin empezó a funcionar correctamente..

```
0% {margin-left: 0;}
20% {margin-left: 0;}
```

Faltó añadirle el % al valor:

```
0% {margin-left: 0%;}
20% {margin-left: 0%;}
```

Un saludo!